# Requirements for Generalist Badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, badges

I was perusing the list of available badges on SE and noticed the Generalist silver-badge defined as `Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags.` This seemed like a reasonable goal and I was about to check my user profile to see how I was doing when I noticed that this badge has never been awarded on Judaism.SE! I checked the [user-with-the-most-reputation's profile page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/37/alex?tab=tags) and I can't seem to understand why he doesn't have the badge. The way I understand it, the Top 40 Tags are the first full page plus one row of the next page when you click on the [tags](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags) link at the top (currently [halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha) through [yom-tov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yom-tov)), and a user's score in a tag is the number to the left of the tag's name in their profile's [tags tab](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/37/alex?tab=tags). It seems to me that @Alex fulfills this criteria (in fact, it seems to me that he has a 15 score in all 40 tags!). Is this a bug? What am I missing?

Comment: Per [Alex's answer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/738) (thank you Alex!), this appears to be by design, so I'm tagging it [meta-tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: Related MSE request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127689/reduce-or-remove-the-200-questions-restriction-on-generalist-badge/242470#242470

Comment: There are actually a whole lot of users who qualify... if the tags would qualify. http://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/164179/generalist-qualifying-users (You're on there, @DoubleAA)

Comment: I also offer [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242481/162102) (MSE).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the fine print [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/generalist-badge-implemented/), each of those 40 tags has to have at least 200 questions in it. So far, only our top 8 tags have reached that point.

Comment: Each of the 40, or the 20?

Comment: @HodofHod All 40. Seems like we have a ways to go before Alex gets his badge :)

Comment: English.SE, which is older, larger, and more vote-ful than we are, hasn't reached it yet either.  This seems like a pretty steep requirement on the community for a silver badge, IMO.

Comment: As of 23rd October 2014, 29 tags have more than 200 questions, and the tag in 40th place has 158 questions. Keep on waiting ☺! ETA for this elusive badge - about 1 year.

Comment: @DoubleAA But at least he doesn't have to do anything (good since he's rarely around anymore). We can work together to earn Alex his badge.

Comment: @user4523 Only 6 tags left each with over 190 qs.

Comment: All good now. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/14/generalist